# Creating an interactive events scheduler

Tags: dojo, calendar, fullcalendar, schedule

I'm attempting to create something with a similar layout to [this](http://visitors2.eventgenie.com/Institute2013/?f=1#!/schedule) schedule page.
See attached screenshot also.

[image].

So what I need is:
 - "Categories" across the top of the scheduler (Vertical dividers).
 - "Timeslots (07:00 07:30, etc..)" down the left of the scheduler.

User's can then add events via modal screens and assign them "Timeslots" and "Categories".
They should then appear in the Schedule in the appropriate locations.

The above mentioned example appears to be using Dojo.
I found [this](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/calendar) calendar widget but am unsure of how to get it to represent "Categories" across the top when using the "Day" view.

Is this possible with the dojo calendar widget? (I've never worked with Dojo before)

Any suggestions as to other frameworks or example's that would provide me with this functionality would be very welcome also.

I've looked at JQuery's fullCalendar plugin and it doesn't seem to provide this functionality (Would be great if someone could prove me wrong!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at Dojo's widget documentation I think the Sub-Column display is what you are looking for. So each Calendar in this case will represent a category. http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/calendar#sub-columns.

I don't think FullCalendar is capable of the category layout, but I think its cool enough to request: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/wiki/Request-a-Feature/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Marcos, I'll look into that and report back if and when I get something implemented.

Comment: @ThomasBuckley Did you ever make that request?  I need to do this, too.

Comment: @BGM We ended up developing out own calendar component from scratch. It is very specific to our needs and didn't want to be hacking the life out of the Dojo or FullCalendar ones!

Comment: Really, would you be willing to share with me? I'm on the painful verge of having to scrounge something together - if you've something that could give me a jumpstart or something that would be great. I'm sure I have peculiar need, too.

Comment: @BGM - Really sorry about the late reply, I did'nt even notice your last comment until now. It's 3 months later now and I assume you got something sorted to meet your needs for the Calendar?

Comment: @ThomasBuckley Actually, no, I got stuck and started working on something else.  I would like to at least talk to you about it - if you view my profile, I have a webform with which you could send me an email and then I could ask a few questions (thanks!).