# Can we divide full calendar's day view agenda into muliple custom columns?

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar script for my app. My requirement is to modify the full calendar day view in such a way that it will have multiple columns in a single day agenda view. Is it possible to do the modification in the full calendar to have this thing ?

-

Comment: Have u tried anything?

Comment: I tried to customize headers.I tried to found it in the documentation.Do you have any idea?

Comment: Whatever u have done please post it in the question

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915925/creating-an-interactive-events-scheduler/18919458#18919458